# What is the difference between manually opened Chrome browser and opened using chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am using Selenium for automating the chrome browser. When I download the files using automated Chrome browser it gives me a warning,

`'This type of file can harm your computer'` with keep or discard options.

But when I manually open chrome and download the files from same site, I won’t get any warnings.
I know I can disable the warnings using, `options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);`

But my question is why I am getting this warning only in automated window?
What is the difference between browser opened using Chrome driver and manually opened browser?

Please help me.

Comment: While performing the same manually, is your chrome option `Privacy -> Protect you and your device from dangerous sites` selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If during your ***manual*** download, in your chrome

```
Settings > Advance Settings

Privacy -> Protect you and your device from dangerous sites (is_checked)
```

The download warning wouldn't be displayed on your browser.

---

On the other hand, not all chrome options are set to the same value during ***automatic*** download from your code. Hence you need to specify :

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
```

---

List of all *command line arguments* for chrome driver goes [here](http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/).

***Note : Though not all of them are certainly of use while using automation and not all of them correspond to a chrome manual setting either.***

Comment: yes you are correct. Do you know, what are the other options which will not set automatically ?

Comment: @ITresearcher - probably all the listed arguments shall help, though only few which correspond to the settings on manual chrome settings shall be of use.